# Reverse Script Execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to reverse the execution order of a script/stored proc?

For example:

SELECT 1

SELECT 2

SELECT 3

Returns:

3

2

1

I am open to workarounds, creative ideas, magic from Mordor and 'not possible' (more prefer Gandalf to step in though).

Background:

I am writing a number of scripts to identify where problems have occurred in a number of stored procedures. (They are effectively just SELECT statements)  Ideally, I would like to write these checks in the order of appearance in the stored procedure (for readability) but I would want it to be executed in the reverse order.

EDIT:

The types of operations these stored procedures are performing are INSERTS and UPDATES (they are part of a larger ETL procedure).  So when a problem occurs, I would like to check how far down the stored proc it got by checking how many records are still left to be updated or inserted and then once I know where it stopped, I can remove the records already inserted and insert the rest.  (This is less important for an update since I can generally just run it again).

Effectively I want my script to execute queries in a LIFO fashion.

Comment: If you are able to change the procedures, store the execution values and output it on the desired order.

Comment: @Jorge Campos To be honest, I do not quite get you but assume I am unable to change the SP's I am performing checks on.  Furthermore, the stored procedure perform operations and do not return a result set.  I updated post with the types of operations I am testing.

Comment: Well if you can't change the SP's code, the best you can do is to add triggers to the involved tables and inside the triggers you populate some sort of audit table. This approach will not entirely solve your problem since you don't know where the trigger was called, I mean, suppose two procedures insert data on table `A` on your audit table will will have two rows for the two inserts but not the info from where it came from. Bottom line for your question is: No, you can not do that without changing procedure codes. AFAIK (just to be clear)

Comment: There's no built-in magic bullet, you're going to have to write code from a fresh perspective.

Comment: Mmm, no problem, was just wondering if there was any known solutions before I go reinvent the wheel.  Meh, what I will probably do, since my script is just select statements, is end each query with a semi-colon, make into a stored proc then just recreate the script using the sys tables to pull out the definition.  Thanks for the help.